# Orientation in 3D space

Tags: c#, 3d, rotation, orientation, direction

I have several inputs: F (go forward), R (turn right), L (turn left), U ("turn up"), D ("turn down"), < ("fall on left side"), > ("fall on right side").

And imagine that on the start I am standing at point (0, 0, 0) where right is X axes, up is Y axes and forward is Z axes (so direction vector would be (0, 0, 1)). I want user to be able to write command like "FFRFFLFLF" and then print right position in 3D space.

For example: commands "FFLFRF<'FRFUFF". Will give me this (I print position after every command):

- (0, 0, 1)
- (0, 0, 2)
- (0, 0, 2)
- (-1, 0, 2)
- (-1, 0, 2)
- (-1, 0, 3)
- (-1, 0, 3)
- (-1, 0, 4)
- (-1, 0, 4)
- (-1, 1, 4)
- (-1, 1, 4)
- (-2, 1, 4)
- (-3, 1, 4)

I ran into problem when I wanted to represent rotation and movement for the given direction. My first approach was to write all possible rotations and directions that could happen. Of course that is not very good approach since it would end up with really ugly code with a lot of repetition.

My question is: What would be best approach for this exact problem? I read about rotation matrices but I am confused how to use them in this exact problem. Can you give me solution or any  hint or advice? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I described turning left/right wrong. By turning left/right I meant rotate left/right (face left or right). My bad, I am sorry. 

For example on start I have position (0, 0, 0) direction (0, 0, 1) and vector describing which axis is going "through my head" (0, 1, 0). If I write command "L" then it would be: position (0, 0, 0), direction (-1, 0, 0) and "head vector" would be still (0, 1, 0).

For command "<" it would be (again from start): position (0, 0, 0), direction (0, 0, 1) and head vector (-1, 0, 0)  (imagine lying on your left side and still looking forward).

Comment: Sorry I misread your question.  No problem (comment deleted)